# Formatting JSON date

Tags: javascript, date

I am converting json date from something like:

```
/Date(1224043200000)/
```

to

> Mon Oct 22 16:37:04 UTC+0800 2012

using

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(dateData.substr(6), 10));
```

Is there any way to change the format to just show the month, date and year (Oct 22, 2012) instead of including the timezone and current day using similar if not the same code as the one I'm already using? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) which has powerful formatting capabilities. Using the [toString FormatSpecifiers](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers), you can provide a custom pattern like this:

```
new Date().toString("MMM dd yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I have another question though, if I were to add the time here, should it be something like new Date().toString("MMM dd yyyy 00:00"); ? Or would the approach be different if the time were to be included? Sorry, I was told that we needed to show the time as well.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. For everybody else: format specifiers can be looked here: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var formattedDate = date.toString().split(" ").slice(1, 4).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)
With something like this :

```
moment(1224043200000).format("MMM Do, YYYY");
```